# How to Block an on-prem AD User from signing into their Office 365 online account through sync?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365

In the Microsoft 365 Admin Portal (Azure) I can block an active user from signing in using the " Block this user" option, pictured:
[image]

However when our on-prem Active Directory server syncs our userbase up to 365, this option is overridden and that user is allowed to sign-in again.

What attribute do I need to set in our on-prem Active Directory server on the user object to match the the "Block this user" option seen in Microsoft 365? I think when I find out this setting, then the value will sync up to 365 and be persisted there.

What I've tried:

1. marking the on-prem AD user account as Disabled (doesn't have an effect in 365 after sync);
2. Moving the user account to a special/custom "Disabled Users" folder in our AD folder but it causes 365 to instead move the user into the Deleted Users area of 365 instead of simply prohibiting that Active User from signing in.

Comment: When you disable the on prem AD user it should set their account as disabled in Azure AD preventing new sign-ins.  You are sure you've tested this?  By default using AAD Connect, that's the way it works.  I can confirm on my end.

Comment: Can also confirm

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the on premises user account will block the Office 365 sign in. If it isn't then you haven't waited for the next sync cycle, or you've misconfigured Azure AD Connect somehow. Disable the on premises user account again and run the following from an elevated Powershell prompt on your Azure AD Connect server: `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta`. Then check the sign-in status in Office 365. If the sign-in still isn't blocked then open a support case with Microsoft from the Office 365 management portal. It's free and MS will troubleshoot the issue with you.

Barring that, you can "unlink" the on premises user account from the Office 365 user account by setting the adminDescription attribute on the on premises user account to `User_NoAzureADSync`.

This will effectively "unlink" the two accounts and will delete the Office 365 user account. Note that any data in Office 365 for the deleted user account will also be deleted, but you'll have 30 days to access it and 30 days to "relink" the accounts if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

Three years late is better than never! We were experiencing the same issue with our domain, even with a "vanilla" install of Azure AD Connect — users disabled in AD didn't have their M365 user's sign-in blocked, and manually blocked users were reverted on the next Azure AD Connect sync.

Not sure if it's because we had the older DirSync and/or Azure AD Sync tools installed in our environment at one point. Regardless, this was the fix for us:

1. Update Azure AD Connect to the latest version

   - Don't skip this step, this is one of the pieces that fixed it for us.
2. Open Azure AD Connect's **Synchronization Rules Editor** app
3. Select the **Inbound** option on the **Direction** filter
4. Select the **Add new rule** button
5. On the **Description** step, enter the following, then select the **Next** button:

   - **Connected System**: select your local AD domain
   - **Connected System Object Type**: select **user** from the dropdown
   - **Metaverse Object Type**: select **person** from the dropdown
   - **Precedence**: enter any value below 100 (the default value of `0` is fine)
6. On the **Scoping filter** step, do the following, then select the **Next** button:

   1. Select the **Add group** button
   2. Select the **Add clause** button
   3. In the newly-created clause, enter the following ([context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties)):

      - **Attribute**: select **userAccountControl** from the dropdown
      - **Operator**: select **ISBITSET** from the dropdown
      - **Value**: enter `2`
7. On the **Join rules** step, do nothing and select the **Next** button
8. On the **Transformations** step, do the following, then select the **Add** button:

   1. Select the **Add transformation** button
   2. In the newly-created transformation, enter the following:

      - **FlowType**: select **Constant** from the dropdown
      - **Target Attribute**: select **accountEnabled** from the dropdown
      - **Source**: enter `False`

Once the above is complete, run a **full sync**:

1. On the server with Azure AD Connect, open an Administrator PowerShell session
2. Run the following command:

   ```perl
   Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
   ```

Once the above was completed, users in M365 / Azure AD correctly had their sign-ins blocked automatically whenever the associated local AD user was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would like to thank
Micah Yeager for your solution !
We followed your tutorial and it's working like a charm !

Just to precise: we set the link type to "Join" in step 5 description.

Thanks for all !

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/551906)